# How do I reference the "display" variable from my inner class, to use in the outer class in my JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel, non-static

I want to enter text into my fourth JPanel, and every time I hit enter to update the first JPanel with the text. I added a keylistener for the return key, it runs a function in the inner class AddSong, that function takes in an arraylist of text, and returns a string. I want to display that string on the JPanel in the first quadrent, but it doesn't work. Right now I believe it is removing the first JPanel, and not updating. I am very confused because this is my first encounter with key events as I am new to programming.

Here's the code:

```
public class MusicPlayer extends JFrame{

  private static final int WIDTH = 400;
  private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
  private JLabel songList,songPlaying,c;
  private JTextField enterSong;
  private AddSong input;

  public MusicPlayer(){

     //Text box enterSong, input passed to actionListener
     input = new AddSong();
     enterSong = new JTextField(10);
     enterSong.addActionListener(input);

     //Numbers the quadrents
     songList = new JLabel(input.printSongs(input.songList),SwingConstants.CENTER);
     songPlaying = new JLabel("2",SwingConstants.CENTER);
     c = new JLabel("c",SwingConstants.CENTER);

     //Makes and sets size of pane
     Container pane = getContentPane();
     pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

     //Add JLabels to panes in the container
     pane.add(songList);
     pane.add(songPlaying);
     pane.add(c);
     pane.add(enterSong);




     //KeyListener - return
     addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){}
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){}
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke){
           if(ke.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
              input.printSongs(input.songList);
           }
        }
     });
     add(songList);
     pack();

     setTitle("Andrew's Music Player");
     setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
     setVisible(true);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  }

  public class AddSong implements ActionListener{

     //List of Songs
     ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<String>();
     String display;

     public AddSong(){
        display = "";
     }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        String song;
        //get the text
        song = enterSong.getText();

        //add current text string to list
        songList.add(song);

        //print songlist
        System.out.print(printSongs(songList));

     }

     public String printSongs(ArrayList<String> songList){
        display = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++){
           display += songList.get(i) + "\n";
        }
        return display;
     }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]){
     MusicPlayer boi = new MusicPlayer();
  }
```

}

Comment: Please show us what line you're getting the error on.  (And don't just give us a line number.  That isn't good enough for us to tell what line is causing the error.)

Comment: I'm getting the error on the line that reads "songList = new JLabel(addSong.display,SwingConstants.CENTER); in the music player function in the music player class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Having a action listener, you can drop the key listener. 
Please note the comments :

```
public class MusicPlayer extends JFrame{

    private static final int WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
    private JLabel songsList,songPlaying,c;
    private JTextField enterSong;
    private AddSong input;

    public MusicPlayer(){

        //Text box enterSong, input passed to actionListener
        input = new AddSong();
        enterSong = new JTextField(10);
        enterSong.addActionListener(input);

        //Numbers the quadrents
        songsList = new JLabel("No songs in list",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        songPlaying = new JLabel("2",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        c = new JLabel("c",SwingConstants.CENTER);

        //Makes and sets size of pane
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));

        //Add JLabels to panes in the container
        pane.add(songsList);
        pane.add(songPlaying);
        pane.add(c);
        pane.add(enterSong);

        //adding a key listenr to the Jframe is not need
        //the  enterSong.addActionListener(input); does the work

        add(songsList);
        pack();

        setTitle("Andrew's Music Player");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public class AddSong implements ActionListener{

        //List of Songs
        ArrayList<String> songList = new ArrayList<>();

        public AddSong(){ }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            String song;
            //get the text
            song = enterSong.getText();

            //add current text string to list
            songList.add(song);

            String songListAsString = printSongs(songList);

            //update display with new song
            songsList.setText(songListAsString);

            //clear text field
            enterSong.setText("");
        }

        public String printSongs(ArrayList<String> songList){

            //using string builder is more efficient
            //to have multiple lines in a JLabel you have to use
            //html tags
            //a JList would be more appropriiate
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<html>");

            for(int i = 0; i < songList.size(); i++){
                sb.append("<p>")
                  .append(songList.get(i))
                  .append("</p>");
            }

            sb.append("</html>");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        MusicPlayer boi = new MusicPlayer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the variable of a class you need to create an instance of it which holds a concrete value for that variable. `addSong.display` on the other hand tries to access the variable without a cocrete instance. This is only allowed for static variables.

You are already creating an instance of `addSong` a few lines later
    input = new addSong();

From this instance you could access the `display` variable. The question then is, if it has already the correct value or if you need to execute some code first in order to properly initialize the value.

And please use only class names beginning with an upper case in Java and try to use nouns as class names.

Comment: It does not already have the correct value, how would I properly initialize the value?

Comment: I don't really understand for what you need this `display` variable. It should be enough that you calculate the text in `actionPerformed` and place it on the `JLabel` `songList`.